# Closing an iPad webapp from HTML/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, web-applications

I'm developing a webapp for iPad and i'm close to finish it (thank's to you guys by the way) but now that I'm pretty close I'm wondering and can't find documentation on how do I tell the browser to close the application onClick? Thanks a lot!

Emilio Peña

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done iPad web apps but I've done them on some other platforms, and in all of them you close the app with:

```
window.close();
```

As a side note, iOS applications don't usually have close buttons, so perhaps you don't even need one?